# Prevent autoloading of last opened document

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

Currently, the default behavior of a Cocoa NSDocument based app is for it to open the last document that was opened automatically. How can I prevent this from happening so I can provide my own behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I did this by adding this method to my NSDocument subclass:

```
- (void)addWindowController:(NSWindowController *)aController {

    //
    // Overwritten to reset all window restoration, we do our own.
    // 
    NSWindow    *window=[aController window];

    if(
        [window respondsToSelector:@selector(setRestorationClass:)]
        && [window respondsToSelector:@selector(setRestorable:)]
        && [window respondsToSelector:@selector(invalidateRestorableState)]
    )
    {
        [window setRestorationClass:Nil];
        [window setRestorable:NO];
        [window invalidateRestorableState];
    }

    [super addWindowController:aController];
}
```

IIRC that was all.

Comment: This didn't work for me (and I have checked the code is getting called).